# How to get maximum difference of column "through time" in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe named 'stock_data' with a MultiIndex index of ('Date', 'StockID') and a column 'Price'. The rows are ordered by date, so for the same stock a later date will have a higher row index. I want to add a new column that for each stock (i.e. group by stock) contains a number with the maximum positive difference between the prices of the stock through time, as in max_price - min_price.

To explain this further, one could calculate this in O(stocks*rows^2) by:

```
for each stock:
    max = 0.0
    for i in range(len(rows)-1):
        for j in range(i+1, len(rows):
            if price[j] - price[i] > max:
                max = price[j] - price[i]
```

How do I do this in pandas without actually calculating every value and assigning it to the right spot of a new column of the dataframe one-at-a-time like the above algorithm (which could probably be improved by sorting but this is besides the point)?

So far, I have only figured out that I can group by 'StockID' with:
`stock_data.groupby(level='Stock')` and pick the column `stock_data.groupby(level='Stock')['Price']`. But something like:

```
stock_data.groupby(level='Stock')['Price'].max() - stock_data.groupby(level='Stock')['Price'].min()
```

is not what I described above because there is no resitriction that the max() must come after the min().

Edit: The accepted solution works. Now I am also wondering if there is a way to penalize that distance by how far the max is from the min, so shorter gains are higher (therefore preferred) over longterm ones with somewhat bigger difference.

For example, maybe we could do cumsum() up to a certain length after min and not till the end? Somehow?

Comment: Instead of `max` and `min` after the `groupby`, try with `cummax` and `cummin`?

Comment: Not exactly. It is convinient for the min but for the max I need to use the one that is ahead and exclude those that are before.

Comment: Maybe it would work if I could apply cummax in the reversed Price values! I am currently trying that but I am having trouble with reversing the group-by object. If anyone knows how, do tell?

Comment: And I actually need to do this separatelly for each stock. I managed to do it for all but it was wrong... This is hard guys..

Comment: Can you provide a sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try `[::-1]` to reverse the order to be able to get the maximum "in the future", then `cummin` and `cummax` after the `groupby`.

```
# sample data
np.random.seed(1)
stock_data = pd.DataFrame({'Price':np.random.randint(0,100, size=14)}, 
                          index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
                              [pd.date_range('2020-12-01', '2020-12-07', freq='D'), 
                               list('ab')], 
                              names=['date','stock'])
                         )
```

and assuming the dates are ordered in time, you can do:

```
stock_data['diff'] = (df.loc[::-1, 'Price'].groupby(level='stock').cummax()
                      - df.groupby(level='stock')['Price'].cummin())
print(stock_data)
                  Price  diff
date       stock             
2020-12-01 a         37    42
           b         12    59
2020-12-02 a         72    42
           b          9    62
2020-12-03 a         75    42
           b          5    66
2020-12-04 a         79    42
           b         64    66
2020-12-05 a         16    60
           b          1    70
2020-12-06 a         76    60
           b         71    70
2020-12-07 a          6     0
           b         25    24
```

Comment: Amazing. I think it works! I only think maybe we would need to re-reverse it before subtracting? Or does the Date index take care of that automatically?

Comment: @Michael I did at first, but index alignment should do it by itself :)

Comment: I added an edit. I don't know if you would also know of a way to get the distance between the max and min.

Comment: @Michael with your edit, I would have a look at `rolling`, but like this it is too vague. another question with more details would be preferred ;)

Comment: I thought of an alternative way to intuitively balance this by buying a variety stocks (some of which should probably have short-term peaks). Not sure how well it will work in the end. I might make a separate question referencing this if I want to do the Edit as well later.